# how to put pagination when sending data as an array to the index page in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

This is the code in my PostController. I send data to the index page as an array
but I have no idea how to put `{{ $post->link()}}` in index page in this situation. I tried so many ways but failed. Is there any solution for this ?

```
public function index()
{
    $posts =  Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5); //add pagination
    $QuestionBank = QuestionBank::all();
    $data = array(
        'posts' => $posts,
        'QuestionBank' => $QuestionBank,
    );
    return view('posts.index', compact('data'));
}
```

index Page will be like this

```
@if(count($data['posts']) > 0)
   @foreach($data['posts'] as $post)
      //display data
   @endforeach
@endif
```

after this I need to add pagination part. Is there any way to add pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your controller like this :

```
public function index()
{
    $posts =  Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5); //add pagination
    $QuestionBank = QuestionBank::all();
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts','QuestionBank'));
}
```

And change your view like this :

```
@if(count($posts) > 0)
   @foreach($posts as $post)
      //display data
   @endforeach
@endif
{{$posts->links()}}
```

And it would work.

Comment: thank you..i will try your solution.. Actually this is also worked {{ $data['posts']->links() }}

Comment: Yes @Senu1998. Mark my answer as correct if t helped you :)